# Wp_query calculate points

Tags: wp-query

I have a query I would like to have help with.

Custom post type car.
Taxonomy brand.

I have users that can send in CPTs that have a taxonomy.
Now I would like to query for points. 
They get one point for each record and a maximum of three points for each taxonomy.

So if they have 10 differnt taxonomies they would score 10 points.
If they have 10 of the same taxonomy they would score 3 points.

Comment: This isn't really specific to WordPress but rather a question of programming logic, isn't it? This is how I would do it: Get all the posts/taxonomies the user used. Group by taxonomy name. Calculate `min(3, count( specific_tax )`, sum those up. 1st case is 1+1+..., 2nd case is 3